# can set $\mathcal{A}$ be written as union of countable set which are rare sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$\mathcal{A}$=the set of all fnite sequences in $l_1$

$l_1$:  the space of sequences of $x_n$ s.t. : $\sum^\infty_1 |x_n|<\infty$

$A_n$ is rare set if the interior of the closure is empty,${Int}\bar A_n=\emptyset$,

is it possible that: $\mathcal{A}=\cup^\infty_{n=1} A_n$ :countable union and $A_n$ is rare

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Did you try any possible $A_n$?

Comment: $A_n=\lbrace(1,1/4,1/9,...,1/n^2,0,0...)\rbrace$ but it would not give us $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: The topology of $\mathcal{A}$ is not obvious to me.  (But maybe all the possible definitions that come to mind turn out to be equivalent.)

Comment: @aschleper Usually, $l_1$ is presumed to have the norm of $$|x| = \sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_n|$$ by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $A_n$ = the set of all sequences of length $n$. It is clear that the union of $A_n$ is $\mathcal A$. It can also be shown that $A_n$ is closed and has an empty interior.